# socket timeout using android marshmallow. Android < 6 works. has anything changed?

Tags: android, sockets, socketexception, android-6.0-marshmallow, socket-timeout-exception

my app needs to connect to a wifi network that doesn't have internet connection and open a socket to the 9402 port.

After I've updated my Nexus 5 to Android 6, it stopped working (socket timeout). My wife's phone with android 5 still works.

Does anybody know if something changed regarding to this?

Thanks

Comment: [Wifi and networking changes - Android M](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html)